# Can permutation tests only prove non i.i.d-ness?

Tags: permutation-test, exchangeability

I just learned about permutation tests through self-study. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_test) we have :

(1) "*The null hypothesis is that all samples come from the same distribution* $H_{0}:F=G$."

and :

(2) "*Under the null hypothesis, the distribution of the test statistic is obtained by calculating all possible values of the test statistic under possible rearrangements of the observed data.*"

I take (2) as synonymous to:

if (1) "*$F = G$*", then (3) "*the sample distribution of the data is exchangeable*" , i.e $\text{(1)} \Rightarrow \text{(3)}$.

So, if it's very unlikely for the data at hand to be exchangeable then that means that it would be very unlikely for it to be in a way such that (1) is true. However, according to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/344821/358963) we have :

$$ \text{i.i.d. } \Rightarrow \text{ exchangeability } \Rightarrow \text{marginals identical}.$$

And the converse implications are all wrong.

So here, I'm wondering if $F = G \Leftrightarrow \text{sample data distribution is i.i.d}$, i.e $\text{(1) }\Leftrightarrow \text{i.i.d. }$ as if e.g all of the $X_1,\dots, X_n$ of our sample data distribution are always just implicitly considered independent.

Or, if they're not necessarily independent then we can't really reject (1) with the permutation test because we have : $\text{non exchangeable} \Rightarrow \text{non i.i.d}$. So, a rejection could either "prove" that the $X_k$ are not independent or that they're not distributed the same, without specifying if it's the former, the latter or both.

Comment: it is a bit hard to follow what you are asking. Would you mind to edit your question for clarity a little?

Comment: What is the $(3)?$

Comment: Sorry for the confusing formulation, all of this is pretty new to me. I tried to rephrase a little, is it better?

Comment: But what is the $(3)?$

Comment: It is "the sample distribution of the data is exchangeable". So the joint distribution of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is invariant for permutations. Just added it.